# The Korean: value for string 'IDS_ERROR_1609' does not contain a legitimate value for table Error column Message

Tags: windows, installshield, installshield-2015

I upgraded my projects from 2009 to 2016, and now one of them is throwing the following errors during compile:

`ISDEV : error -7354: The Korean: 한국어 value for string 'IDS__DatabaseFolder_ChangeFolder' does not contain a legitimate value for table Control column Text
ISDEV : error -7354: The Korean: 한국어 value for string 'IDS_ERROR_1609' does not contain a legitimate value for table Error column Message
ISDEV : error -7354: The Korean: 한국어 value for string 'IDS_ERROR_2841' does not contain a legitimate value for table Error column Message
ISDEV : error -7354: The Korean: 한국어 value for string 'IDS_ERROR_2860' does not contain a legitimate value for table Error column Message`

The link https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/articles/en_US/ERRDOC/Error-7354-When-Building-MSI provides the solution but for the above error prompts i am not sure what the string i have to replace.

For Example from the error `ISDEV : error -7354: The Korean: 한국어 value for string 'IDS_ERROR_2841' does not contain a legitimate value for table Error column Message` the string in the table is `오류 대화 상자에 [확인] 단추가 없습니다`. How do i update the string in this case?

Answer (score 4):

To address these as described in the KB article you linked, I would suggest using the String Editor view. You can paste the string id (IDS_ERROR_2841) into the top to filter down to just a couple strings, and then look for the Korean translation.

Much of the time that this error is issued for an East Asian language string, it is due to the presence of square brackets that should not be there, such as the substring `[확인]` in what you quote. The simplest and safest change to make is to replace the left bracket `[` with an escaped left bracket `[\[]` and the right bracket `]` with an escaped right bracket `[\]]`.

This typically reflects a problem with the string that InstallShield provided, but if you added the strings in an earlier version of InstallShield, and migrated, any corrections made by InstallShield will not be part of your strings. If you are in this scenario, and haven't modified any of the provided strings, you could instead try importing the current Korean strings (language ID 1042) to see if it addresses any of the errors. Note that doing so will replace any strings that are part of the Korean strings file, so any strings that this does not fix are either still a problem in InstallShield, or are custom strings in your project.

In a few cases, there can be an invalid character included for the type of the column, such as a character that can not be included in a filename. I don't believe this applies for any of the cases you mention, so your cases are probably all unescaped square brackets.

Comment: I have tried to replace the left bracket [ with an escaped left bracket [\[] and the right bracket ] with an escaped right bracket [\]]. This is resulting in the new error  "The Chinese (Hong Kong): 中文(繁體) translation for string identifier IDS_ERROR_10 includes characters that are not available on code page 950."

Comment: Well, either the wrong string got "fixed", or more likely this is another error that you didn't see until resolving the problems with the Korean strings. Note the different error number. For those, you can either try to figure out what character is not on the code page and replace it, or you can select to use a UTF-8 Database (which has other problems) in the Releases view, or ask a new question.

Answer (score -4):

Remove last {{ (for example for Greek):

`Παρουσιάστηκε ένα σφάλμα κατά την εγκατάσταση του εξαρτήματος συναρμολόγησης [2]. HRESULT: [3]. {{διασύνδεση συναρμολόγησης: [4], συνάρτηση: [5], {{όνομα συναρμολόγησης: [6]}}`

InstallShield 2016 version:

`Παρουσιάστηκε ένα σφάλμα κατά την εγκατάσταση του εξαρτήματος συναρμολόγησης [2]. HRESULT: [3]. {{διασύνδεση συναρμολόγησης: [4], συνάρτηση: [5], όνομα συναρμολόγησης: [6]}}`